# Extjs Combobox set color to specific item

Tags: extjs, combobox

Is there a way to set color of last item (or last two items) of combobox items, i tried to use TPL but didn't work. Here is the TPL defination with XTeplate which was defined before i updated. Thanks a lot.

```
var resultTplHesap103Ekod = new Ext.XTemplate(
 '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item">',
 '<h3><span> {val}  </h3>',
 '<span style="color:blue"> {dsc}  </span>', '</div></tpl>'
);
```

From @MMT,

I changed codes like this.

```
var resultTplHesap360Ekod = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="(xindex ) &gt; (xcount-1)">',
               '<tpl>',
                    '<div class="x-combo-list-item">',
                    '<h3> {val}  </h3>',
                    '<span style="color:red"> {dsc}  </span>', 
                    '</div>',
               '</tpl>',
            '</tpl>',

            '<tpl if="(xindex ) &lt; (xcount-2)">',
               '<tpl>',
                    '<div class="x-combo-list-item">',
                    '<h3> {val}  </h3>',
                    '<span style="color:blue"> {dsc}  </span>', 
                    '</div>',
               '</tpl>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>'
    );

var comboHsp360EkodHarcama = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            fieldLabel : '',
            labelSeparator : '',
            triggerAction : 'all',
            mode : 'local',
            store : storeHesapTasinirHeskod360,
            displayField : 'dsc',
            valueField : 'val',
            emptyText : 'Damga Vergisi Türü',
            forceSelection : true,
            hidden : true,
            forceSelection : true,
            tpl : resultTplHesap360Ekod,
            width : 300,
            listClass : 'x-combo-list-item'
        });

var storeHesapTasinirHeskod360 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            url : '../gen/hesapTasinir.ajax',
            root : 'list',
            fields : ['dsc', 'val']
        });
```

Now code is working thank a lot @MMT, the last item (for now) is red that was important for me, but now i have another problem. When i select this last RED item it appears black in text fiel at the top ob box. Could you please help me to make it remain RED. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="(xindex ) &gt; (xcount-2)">',
               '<tpl>',
                    '<div class="x-combo-list-item">',
                    '<h3> {value}  </h3>',
                    '<span style="color:red"> {name}  </span>', 
                    '</div>',
               '</tpl>',
            '</tpl>',

            '<tpl if="(xindex ) &lt; (xcount-2)">',
               '<tpl>',
                    '<div class="x-combo-list-item">',
                    '<h3> {value}  </h3>',
                    '<span style="color:blue"> {name}  </span>', 
                    '</div>',
               '</tpl>',
            '</tpl>',

        '</tpl>'
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MMT but it still didn't work and i started to think that there is a piece of code which ovverides our code here. I am sure that i am on right combobox but still last item text is black.

Comment: By the way, i just noticied that our TPL code is rendered when page is loaded, but i need something after store is load into combobox it should be rendered. Can there be a clue for you here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: set the `tpl` property of combo with this template

Comment: I already did it. But stil not working. I will send all code above. Thanks @MMT

Comment: Dear @MMT it worked but when i select red item it seems black on the top of box but i want it still remain red; do you know how to handle this. thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to use displayTpl to solve this? For the selected item the color must be remained still red. @MMT