# ExtJS make one combo item different

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

Maybe someone can give some ideas, how to add item to the end of combobox dropdown, and make it "different" for example put separator before it or make it bold. Combobox uses sorted (by name) store, and on load there is added item which I want to make different.

```
Ext.define('Plugin.workspace.store.FavouriteCarStore', {
        extend : 'Plugin.workspace.store.CarStore',
        alias : 'store.favouritecar',

        filters : [{
                    property : 'favorite',
                    value : true
                }],

        listeners : {
            load : function(store) {
                var rec = {
                    id : 'showAll',
                    name : 'Show All',
                    favorite : true
                };

                store.add(rec);
            }
        }

    });
```

combo uses this store:

```
    tbar : [{
    xtype : 'combo',
    width : 200,
    editable: false,
    store : {
        type : 'favouritecar'
    },

    bind : {
        value : '{workspace}'
    },

    tpl : '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for="."><li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{name}</li></tpl></ul>',
    displayTpl : '<tpl for=".">{name}</tpl>',
    listeners : {
        'select' : 'onSelectWorkspace'
    }
}].
```

This code adds item, which looks like others, and places it depending on sort.

I use 5.1 ExtJS.

**EDIT: solution to add item to list end.**

```
            sorters : [{
                    sorterFn : function(rec1, rec2) {
                        if (rec1.id != 'showAll' && rec2.id != 'showAll') {
                            return ((rec1.get('name') > rec2.get('name')) ? 1 : (rec1.get('name') === rec2.get('name') ? 0 : -1));
                        } else {
                            return ((rec1.id == 'showAll') ? 1 : -1);
                        }
                    }
                }],
```

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but can't you achieve this with css using the `:last` selector and give it a `border-top` for example?

Comment: ok not bad idea,
how to add item to the end. because sorting causes it appear in different places in dropdown list.
Maybe any code as example?

Comment: I think after looking into it a little bit deeper it can't be done with css, because the data of the combobox seems to be set using the aria attribute. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250768/extjs-combobox-set-color-to-specific-item

Comment: find sollution how to add item to last place, only left to change style.

Comment: Can you look at the dom of the combobox and see if the data is set using the `aria` attribute or that the combobox has a attribute called `data-ref`? If the combobox has a `data-ref` attribute there will be a `ul` in the dom with a `data-ref` and with the same value.

Comment: it has `data-ref="inputEl"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Use a custom `cls` on the combo's `listConfig`:

```
listConfig: {
    cls: 'thisComboMakesLastItemDifferent'        
},
```

And then use CSS to make the last item different:

```
.thisComboMakesLastItemDifferent li:last-child {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Method 2**

Since you are marking your "different" item with `favorite: true`, you can code it in the template:

```
tpl: '<tpl for="."><li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item favorite-{favorite}">{name}</li></tpl>',
```

And then, again, use CSS:

```
.favorite-true:before {
    content: 'FAV: '
}
```

Note that the first method focuses on making the *last* item different regardless of *what* item it is. The second method makes *specific* item different (you need extra logic to make sure it is the last; you have one already).

See both methods in action: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sdj

Comment: Yes, i used first method, because all items in combo are favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `store.insert(store.indexOf(store.last()) index, rec)` or `store.insert(store.count() - 1, rec)`?

```
load : function(store) {
    somewhere.static.setShowAllAsLastRecordOfStore(store);
}

filterchange(store, filters, eOpts) {
    somewhere.static.setShowAllAsLastRecordOfStore(store);
}

sort(store, eOpts) {
    somewhere.static.setShowAllAsLastRecordOfStore(store);
}

setShowAllAsLastRecordOfStore: function(store) {
    var rec = {
            id : 'showAll',
            name : 'Show All',
            favorite : true
        };

    store.remove(store.findRecord('id', 'showAll'));

    store.insert(store.indexOf(store.last()) index, rec);
        // or
    store.insert(store.count() - 1, rec);
}
```

Comment: because of sorting, `store.insert(store.count() - 1, rec);`  not puts in last position. Also not sure, how to add css, only to last item of combo?

Comment: On refresh it, makes infinitive loop :)

Comment: Lol! Completely forgot. Make sense though. Then you could put the code in a function (the prevent duplicate code) and call that function from within the `sort` and `filterchange` listener?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, also can you write how to add css to last item?